# How to insert document with collection.update_many() into Collection (MongoDB) using Pymongo (No Duplicated)

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I insert Document into Collection with collection.update() because each data I have a `postID` to different. I want to when I run if a post was inserted in MongoDB, the post will be updated (not insert a new post with `postID` overlapping with `postID` first). This is a structure of my data:

```
comment1 = [
   {
     'commentParentId': parent_content.text,
     'parentId': parent_ID,
     'posted': child_time.text,
     'postID':child_ID,
     'author':
          {
           'name': child_name.text
          },
     'content': child_content.text
   },
   ...............
]
```

This is my code, i used to insert data :

```
client = MongoClient()
db = client['comment_data2']
db.collection_data = db['comments']
for i in data_comment:
   db.collection_data.update_many(
        {db.collection_data.find({"postID": {"$in": i["postID"]}})},
        {"$set": i},
        {'upsert': True}
   )
```

But I have a Error : `TypeError: filter must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, or other type that inherits from collections.Mapping` in line `{'upsert': True}`. And `{db.collection_data.find({"postID": {"$in": i["postID"]}})}` is right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this code:

```
db.collection_data.update_many(
    {"postId": i["postID"]},
    {"$set":i},
    upsert = True
)
```

Comment: Error: `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` which `upsert = True`

Comment: {  "upsert" :True } can solve that error because 3rd argument is type of object.

Comment: I tried your solution, but my Error is not solved (same error in the post)

Comment: `db.collection_data.updateMany( {"postId": i["postID"]}, {"$set":i}, { upsert: True } )`

Comment: i tried this code and got no error.please send me your new code.

Comment: @AliHallaji I tried your solution (I copy your solution and pasted in my project) and have a Error : `TypeError: filter must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, or other type that inherits from collections.Mapping`

Comment: @Michael I tried your solution and have an Error: `NameError: name 'upsert' is not defined`

Comment: what is the type of postID?

Comment: type of postID : str

Comment: `filter must be an instance of dict` I think `{db.collection_data.find({"postID": {"$in": i["postID"]}})}` is wrong

Comment: Thanks, that is my mistake. But I follow a document `https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/` and I saw: filter: The selection criteria for the update. The same query selectors as in the find() method are available.

Comment: so, why are you didn't use collection_data.find() to find postID?

Comment: OK, my code has been written for python by pymongo module. I think you are using JavaScript code, it’s because of your syntax error . Is it true?